# Automatic data exclusion in aggregations with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

In my Mongoose models, I've set sensitive data to `select: false` so it isn't returned with queries by default:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<User, UserModelType, {}, UserQueryHelpers>({
    username: {...},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, validate: [validator.isEmail, 'invalid email'], select: false },
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    profilePicUrl: { type: String },
    emailVerified: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false, select: false },
    [...]
});
```

To my shock, **I realized that this doesn't work in all scenarios.** Namely **`lookup` queries** in aggregations don't respect `select: false`.

```
const result = await KarmaLogEntry.aggregate()
    .match({
        createdAt: { $gte: startOfCurrentMonth }
    })
    .group({
        _id: "$user",
        totalPoints: { $sum: "$points" }
    })
    .sort({ 'totalPoints': -1 })
    .limit(10)
    .lookup({
        from: "users",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "user",
    })
    .unwind('$user')
    .exec();
```

**This returns all the sensitive fields!**

I know that I can exclude fields with an additional `$project` stage:

```
.lookup({
    from: "users",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "user",
    pipeline: [
        {
            $project: {
                username: '$username',
                displayName: '$displayName',
                profilePicUrl: '$profilePicUrl',
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

However, if I ever forget to add this for an endpoint, I will leak sensitive user data. **Is there a way to apply `select: false` to all forms of MongoDB queries, including aggregation and lookups?**

Comment: There is one method described in the post, to override the clean method. Does that helps. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1596

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Same problem, I have to **remember** to call this method on each request. The great thing about `select: false` is that I have to **opt-in** to send sensitive data, not **opt-out**.